# What kind of MAF sensor is this?

Tags: sensor, maf

A Bosch MAF sensor from a 1994-1996 Volvo looks like this:

[image]

I have read about different types of these old sensors and they all mention a "wire", however I cannot see a wire in this sensor, just a board and two vanes. What kind of sensor is it?

Comment: Test the conductors inside of the recessed plug part, ohms should rise and your rmps rise, you should have a ground wire "continuity" hot wire (12 to 5v depends) and then signal wires and maybe a extra signal ground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bosch MAF you have is most likely a hot film and not a hot wire sensor. Both the hot wire and hot film versions can function in the same way, in that they register the cooling as a voltage change, which then registers as the mass of air being drawn into the system. Hot film MAFs can also send a frequency to the computer to calculate the amount of air, though I don't believe this is the way your Volvo one works.

You can read about hot wire/film MAFs on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_sensor#Hot_wire_sensor_(MAF)).

Comment: That makes sense.